How to ignore empty values in a column in Excel VBA?
I have a table with email addresses and the contact person. Not all contact persons have an email address. I want to ignore the empty Email column values.



Email
Contact Person




jesse@teamrocket.com
Jesse



Meowth


james@teamrocket.com
James



Sub SendMultipleEmails() 

    Dim OutApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As MailItem

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
    ' Since B is the second row and this list is complete
    msg_1 = "To PRotect the world from devastation?" & vbLf & vbLf
  
    For r = 2 To lr 'To ignore the header

        If Range("A" & r).Value <> "" then Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With OutMail 
            .To = Range("A" & r).Value 
            .Subject = "Team Rocket Chant" 
            .Body = msg_1
            .CC = Range("C" & r).Value 

            .Display
        End With 

    Next r 

    Set OutMail = Nothing 
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub 

I get a display of the email with an empty email address. I want to create emails with an email address only.

Problem is at your IF...THEN block. Your With block is running either IF statement is TRUE or FALSE. So, place With block inside IF block. Try-
Option Explicit

Sub SendMultipleEmails()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim lr As Long, r As Long
Dim msg_1 As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
' Since B is the second row and this list is complete
msg_1 = "To PRotect the world from devastation?" & vbLf & vbLf

    For r = 2 To lr 'To ignore the header
        If Range("A" & r).Value <> "" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = Range("A" & r).Value
                .Subject = "Team Rocket Chant"
                .Body = msg_1
                .CC = Range("C" & r).Value
                .Display
            End With
        End If
    Next r
    
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

